# Diferença entre função compact e atribuição literal de array

Tags: php, array, desempenho, benchmark

De acordo com a documentação do PHP, a função `compact`.

> Para cada um dos parâmetros passados, `compact()` procura uma variável com o nome especificado na tabela de símbolos e a adiciona no array de saída de forma que o nome da variável será a chave e o seu conteúdo será o valor para esta chave.

Ou seja, ela pode criar um  `array` baseado nos nomes das variáveis do escopo local.

Costumo utilizar essa funções em alguns casos para poder transformar em `array` alguns valores que estou utilizando em variáveis.

Por exemplo:

```
function process_request(array $data) {
      $body = $data['response']->getBody();
      $headers = $data['request']->getHeaders();

       // Resto do código
}

$request = new Request;
$response = new Response;
process_request(compact('response', 'request'));
```

No caso específico acima, poderia ser feito também com atribuição literal de um `array`:

```
process_request(['response' => $response, 'request' => $request])
```

Eu costumo usar `compact` ao invés da atribuição direta simplesmente por causa da estética (vaidade com o código). Porém me vem as vezes em mente que `compact` é uma função, já a atribuição direta não, e que isso pode implicar na performance.

Sendo assim, pergunto:

- Qual das duas formas são as mais apropriadas?
- Todas as versões do PHP são compatíveis com a função `compact`?
- Por `compact` ser uma função, e não um construtor da linguagem, o torma mais lento do que a atribuição literal?

Comment: Não entendi bem a função do `compact`, ele procura variaveis no mesmo escopo com os mesmos nomes passados e converte em um array com os respectivos valores?

Comment: @RafaelAcioly sim, exatamente. Você nunca usou pelo visto, né :p

Answer (score 3):

- Eu não acho que você encontrará quaisquer ganhos de desempenho usando qualquer um dos métodos disponíveis, em detrimento de outro.
  Isso realmente se resume a legibilidade e o que faz mais sentido ao olhar para o código.
- A função está disponível a partir da versão PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7.
- Utilizo o `compact()` no Laravel 5 para o desenvolvimento de um sistema de RP e não tenho nenhum problema quanto a lentidão.

Answer (score -2):

função compact está disponivel (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7, PHP 8)
compact — Cria um array contendo variáveis e seus valores.
em vez de usar um array o compact ajuda pelo facto de vc não precisar itera-lo, eu normalmente uso para valores singulares, ou seja atribuir um único valor seja provido de um array ou não. aconselho a não usa-lo em vectores com mais de uma dimensão ou com um conjunto de chaves e valores (dados). Pois nestes casos passa mesmo o vector na página ou em um objecto na qual pretendes envia-lo.